# Efficient-yet-terse way to add all the arrays in a composite type?

Tags: julia

I came up with 2 ways to add all the arrays in a pair of composite types. The first way (`add_structs_1`) takes 4 seconds to run and the second way  (`add_structs_2`)  takes 0.15 seconds. But the second way requires a lot more code...I have to explicitly mention each field in the composite type. Is there a way to get the efficiency of `add_structs_2`, without explicitly listing each field?

```
type SampleStruct
    a::Vector{Float64}
    k::Matrix{Float64}
    e_axis::Vector{Float64}
    e_dev::Vector{Float64}
    e_scale::Vector{Float64}
end

function add_structs_1(tgt::SampleStruct, src::SampleStruct)
    for n in names(SampleStruct)
        for i in 1:length(tgt.(n))
            tgt.(n)[i] += src.(n)[i]
        end
    end
end

function add_structs_2(tgt::SampleStruct, src::SampleStruct)
    for i in 1:length(tgt.a)
        tgt.a[i] += src.a[i]
    end

    for i in 1:length(tgt.k)
        tgt.k[i] += src.k[i]
    end

    for i in 1:length(tgt.e_axis)
        tgt.e_axis[i] += src.e_axis[i]
    end

    for i in 1:length(tgt.e_dev)
        tgt.e_dev[i] += src.e_dev[i]
    end

    for i in 1:length(tgt.e_scale)
        tgt.e_scale[i] += src.e_scale[i]
    end
end

function time_add_structs(f::Function)
    src = SampleStruct(ones(3), ones(3,3), [1.], [1.], [1.])
    tgt = SampleStruct(ones(3), ones(3,3), [1.], [1.], [1.])

    @time for i in 1:1000000
        f(tgt, src)
    end
end

time_add_structs(add_structs_1)
time_add_structs(add_structs_1)

time_add_structs(add_structs_2)
time_add_structs(add_structs_2)

time_add_structs(add_structs_3)
time_add_structs(add_structs_3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more julian approach to `add_structs_1` is to make the inner loop a separate function, this allows the compiler to specialize the function on each type in the `SampleStruct` and gives quite a speedup.

By profiling the code it was visible that the time to execute `names(SampleStruct)` were quite significant, and this should be done in each iteration of your benchmark, by making it a global constant some time is gained and the function now looks like:

```
function add_array(a::AbstractArray,b::AbstractArray)
    for i in 1:length(a)
        a[i] += b[i]
    end
end
const names_in_struct = names(SampleStruct)
function add_structs_3(tgt::SampleStruct, src::SampleStruct)
    for n in names_in_struct
        add_array(tgt.(n),src.(n))
    end
end
```

The function is now within a factor of four of `add_structs_2`

The  metaprogramming approach is more complicated but gives the same performance as `add_structs_2`

```
ex = Any[]
for n in names(SampleStruct)
    t = Expr(:.,:tgt, QuoteNode(n))
    s = Expr(:.,:src, QuoteNode(n))
    e=quote
        for i in 1:length($t)
            $t[i] += $s[i]
        end
    end
    push!(ex,e)
end
eval(quote function add_structs_4(tgt::SampleStruct, src::SampleStruct) 
     $(Expr(:block,ex...))
    end 
end)
```

Answer (score 4):

Each of those for loops could be replaced with a one-liner, making the long version just this:

```
function add_structs_3(tgt::SampleStruct, src::SampleStruct)
    tgt.a[:] += src.a
    tgt.k[:,:] += src.k
    tgt.e_axis[:] += src.e_axis
    tgt.e_dev[:] += src.e_dev
    tgt.e_scale[:] += src.e_scale
end
```

This is the same length as `add_structs_1` but slower because it actually builds a temporary array and then does the assignment. You could also use some metaprogramming to generate the longer code.

Comment: On my computer `add_structs_3` is 10x slower than `add_structs_2`. That's faster than `add_structs_1`, but still too much overhead for my application. (My actual structs have many more fields than `SampleStruct`.) I was hoping not to have to use metaprogramming, but perhaps that's the only way. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I was going to add some code to use metaprogramming to generate the fast version, but I hit a bug that distracted me (and has now been fixed). I'll add that later when I get a chance.

Comment: Simply putting the `@devec` macro from [Devectorize.jl](https://github.com/lindahua/Devectorize.jl) in front of each assignment makes this just as fast as `add_structs_2`.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that should get all the performance of the best case is to combine Daniel's and Stefan's answers: define addition as a separate function just like in Daniel's solution, instead of iterating over the names list each field manually like in Stefan's answer.